# error: unsupported SysV option when use groovy .execute()

Tags: groovy

here is my code:

`"ps -o pid -o cmd -e|grep -E 'cmake /home/roroco/.clion'".execute()` and I get `error: unsupported SysV option`, but when I try this cmd on terminal, it work, how to fix it, I have seen [ask ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101490/unsupported-sysv-option-when-invoking-ps), it doesn't work, I have only one /bin/ps

Comment: What does `command -v ps` say in the terminal when you run it? What do you get for that from groovy?

Comment: @EtanReisner it show `/bin/ps`

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with prepend `["/bin/sh", "-c"`, before groovy `.execute()`, here is my code:

```
static String sh(String... args) {
    String cmd = args.join(" ")
    Out.out "run cmd: ${cmd}", "ro.Out.out(Out.groovy)"
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer()
    StringBuffer err = new StringBuffer()
    Process p = ["/bin/sh", "-c", cmd].execute()
    p.consumeProcessOutput(out, err)
    int status = p.waitFor();
    if (status != 0) {
        String msg = err.toString()
        if (msg == "") {
            msg = out.toString()
        }

        throw new Sh.Err("cmd: ${cmd}\n\nstderr: ${msg}")
    } else {
        out.toString()
    }
}
```